# SLURM Jobscript respond to password request

Tags: linux, command-line, zsh, slurm

I have currently this job script where I need to connect to a proxy to access my needed files:

```
#!/usr/local_rwth/bin/zsh




#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=20G



#SBATCH --job-name=Dataloading

#SBATCH --output=output.%J.txt



source /rwthfs/rz/cluster/home/dk904271/miniconda3/bin/activate

voms-proxy-init --voms cms --vomses /rwthfs/rz/cluster/home/dk904271/.grid-security/vomses
```

but after the last command I am requested to enter the Gridkey. **How can I tell my jobscript to enter the password?** just putting down the password as the next command seems to not work. There isn't any option to put the password in the initial command either.

Comment: Why did you tag this `PowerShell` ?

Comment: Not sure thought there would be a basic powershell comand solving my issue. But you are right I corrected my tag to zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/voms-proxy-init), the `voms-proxy-init` command accepts a `-pwstdin` argument to

> Allow[s] passphrase from stdin

So you can try something like

```
voms-proxy-init --voms cms --vomses /rwthfs/rz/cluster/home/dk904271/.grid-security/vomses <<< "the_password"
```

or

```
echo "the_password" | voms-proxy-init --voms cms --vomses /rwthfs/rz/cluster/home/dk904271/.grid-security/vomses
```

Another option is to use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Comment: Thank you, I used the first solution. When I tried it first it wouldnt work because I typed in the password after -pwstdin, but in fact I had to create a file containing the password.